# SQLAlchemy - NoReferencedTableError exception when accessing columns of alias of a reflected table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a problem with aliasing a table that was reflected from existing remote (i.e. the data is provided by a third party) DB.

Here's my code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
engine = create_engine(URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    ...
), future=True)
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.clear()
Store = Table('Store', metadata, autoload_with=engine, resolve_fks=False)
print(Store.c)

# Output:
ImmutableColumnCollection(Store.Id, Store.1CStatus, Store.CRMStatus, Store.ModifiedDate, Store.CRM_id, Store.1C_Id, Store.Name, Store.MainPriceList, Store.Adress, Store.PhoneNumber, Store.Driving, Store.Schedule, Store.Foto, Store.Stocks, Store.ERP_ID, Store.ERPStatus, Store.CheckoutMachine, Store.MainStock, Store.IsActive, Store.StoreFormat, Store.Parent_1CID, Store.LoadIStore, Store.Code)
```

I can connect and make queries just fine, but i need to join this table on itself. I tried making an alias for the `Store` table:

```py
ParentStore = Table.alias()
print(ParentStore.c)
```

, but accessing `c` collection causes an exception:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../script.py", line 257, in <module>
    print(get_data())
  File ".../script.py", line 132, in get_data
    print(ParentStore.c)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1113, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 737, in columns
    self._populate_column_collection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 1643, in _populate_column_collection
    self.element._generate_fromclause_column_proxies(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 694, in _generate_fromclause_column_proxies
    fromclause._columns._populate_separate_keys(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 1293, in _populate_separate_keys
    cols = list(iter_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 695, in <genexpr>
    col._make_proxy(fromclause) for col in self.c
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2037, in _make_proxy
    fk = [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2038, in <listcomp>
    ForeignKey(f.column, _constraint=f.constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1113, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2489, in column
    raise exc.NoReferencedTableError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'Store.MainPriceList' could not find table 'PriceListRegion' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'Id'
```

I have no idea why SQLAlchemy is suddenly trying to resolve `PriceListRegion` table, i've got no need for it.

UPD:
Not sure what kind of additional info would be required, but here is content of `metadata.tables`, **after** assigning an alias:

```
FacadeDict({
    'Store': Table(
        'Store',
        MetaData(),
        Column('Id', INTEGER(), table=<Store>, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=Identity(start=1, increment=1)),
        Column('1CStatus', INTEGER(), table=<Store>, nullable=False),
        Column('CRMStatus', INTEGER(), table=<Store>, nullable=False),
        Column('ModifiedDate', DATETIME(), table=<Store>, nullable=False),
        Column('CRM_id', NVARCHAR(length=36), table=<Store>, nullable=False),
        Column('1C_Id', CHAR(length=9, collation='Cyrillic_General_CI_AS'), table=<Store>, nullable=False),
        Column('Name', NVARCHAR(), table=<Store>, nullable=False),
        Column('MainPriceList', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('PriceListRegion.Id'), table=<Store>),
        Column('Adress', VARCHAR(length=150, collation='Cyrillic_General_CI_AS'), table=<Store>),
        Column('PhoneNumber', VARCHAR(length=50, collation='Cyrillic_General_CI_AS'), table=<Store>),
        Column('Driving', VARCHAR(length=80, collation='Cyrillic_General_CI_AS'), table=<Store>),
        Column('Schedule', VARCHAR(length=250, collation='Cyrillic_General_CI_AS'), table=<Store>),
        Column('Foto', VARCHAR(length=80, collation='Cyrillic_General_CI_AS'), table=<Store>),
        Column('Stocks', INTEGER(), table=<Store>),
        Column('ERP_ID', NVARCHAR(length=36), table=<Store>),
        Column('ERPStatus', INTEGER(), table=<Store>),
        Column('CheckoutMachine', INTEGER(), table=<Store>),
        Column('MainStock', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('Stocks.Id'), table=<Store>),
        Column('IsActive', INTEGER(), table=<Store>),
        Column('StoreFormat', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('StoreFormats.Id'), table=<Store>),
        Column('Parent_1CID', CHAR(length=9, collation='Cyrillic_General_CI_AS'), table=<Store>),
        Column('LoadIStore', INTEGER(), table=<Store>),
        Column('Code', INTEGER(), table=<Store>), schema=None
    )
})
```

Comment: Never mind, it's trivially reproducible with any table that has a foreign key constraint.  Evidently the aliased object doesn't "know" that the fk is not resolved and tries to access the foreign table and errors because it isn't in the metadata.    It might be worth opening a [discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions) on GitHub to determine whether this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [snakecharmerb's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72499839/sqlalchemy-noreferencedtableerror-exception-when-accessing-columns-of-alias-of#comment128082804_72499839), i've opened up a [discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8099) on SQLAlchemy's GitHub, and it was confirmed that SQLAlchemy trying to resolve aliased table's foreign key constraints was indeed a [bug](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8101).  Fixed in SQLAlchemy [1.4.38](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-04dc2abf7e7566c5218d2d18284015e9).